# Windows 10, C#, Notification

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

Доброго времени суток.
Вопрос таков: как добавить оповещение в Windows 10, используя WindowsForm?
В оповещении нужно вывести немножко текста и проиграть мелодию, которую можно самому выбрать.

Оповещения, это те, что появляются справа здесь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Windows 10 обычный baloon hint (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms160065(v=vs.110).aspx) работает нотификация. Правда насчет кастомного звука я не уверен.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас имеется приложение WinForms и вы хотите из этого приложения отобразить оповещение, то вам можно преобразовать ваше WinForms приложение в пакет appx с помощью моста Project Cenntenial. После преобразования вы сможете и использовать многие возможности Windows 10 и кроме того опубликовать ваше .Net приложение в Store. 
Этот мост пока что еще в стадии разработки, но первый релиз будет уже в следующей инсайдерской сборке.